# Registering Multiple Same-Host Services

Tags: consul

I am using [the Consul API](https://www.consul.io/api/agent/service.html#register-service) to register a local web-service running on various ports on my local machine. My end-goal is to be able to run multiple backends and load balance against them on different ports.

I am running a local Consul server of one node for development in a Vagrant VM. I have registered the first instance of my service:

```
{
  "Node": {
    "ID": "49d3be4b-5ee5-5f0f-e145-dcb1782e5b4b",
    "Node": "localhost",
    "Address": "127.0.0.1",
    "Datacenter": "dc1",
    "TaggedAddresses": {
      "lan": "127.0.0.1",
      "wan": "127.0.0.1"
    },
    "Meta": {
      "consul-network-segment": ""
    },
    "CreateIndex": 5,
    "ModifyIndex": 6
  },
  "Services": {
    "consul": {
      "ID": "consul",
      "Service": "consul",
      "Tags": [],
      "Address": "",
      "Port": 8300,
      "EnableTagOverride": false,
      "CreateIndex": 5,
      "ModifyIndex": 5
    },
    "rusty": {
      "ID": "rusty",
      "Service": "rusty",
      "Tags": [
        "rusty",
        "rust"
      ],
      "Address": "127.0.0.1",
      "Port": 8001,
      "EnableTagOverride": false,
      "CreateIndex": 247,
      "ModifyIndex": 491
    }
  }
}
```

You can see my service, `rusty`, registered on port 8001. The strange thing is that when I register the same service on a different port, Consul supersedes port 8001 with the new service port.

Is there not a way to run multiple backends for a service on different ports on the same host?

Answer (score 3):

Try to check that you are registering services with different IDs. For complete info see the [parameters](https://www.consul.io/api/agent/service.html#parameters) for `/agent/service/register` endpoint.

Here is an example with two `rusty` service instances with different IDs `rusty1` and `rusty2`

`{
    "Node": {
        "ID": "eff2fae3-6ee5-5de7-bf1a-c041992a1d6a",
        "Node": "FB20160707",
        "Address": "192.168.1.66",
        "Datacenter": "dc1",
        "TaggedAddresses": {
            "lan": "192.168.1.66",
            "wan": "192.168.1.66"
        },
        "Meta": {},
        "CreateIndex": 5,
        "ModifyIndex": 6
    },
    "Services": {
        "consul": {
            "ID": "consul",
            "Service": "consul",
            "Tags": [],
            "Address": "",
            "Port": 8300,
            "EnableTagOverride": false,
            "CreateIndex": 5,
            "ModifyIndex": 5
        },
        "rusty1": {
            "ID": "rusty1",
            "Service": "rusty",
            "Tags": [],
            "Address": "10.10.10.10",
            "Port": 8001,
            "EnableTagOverride": false,
            "CreateIndex": 16,
            "ModifyIndex": 28
        },
        "rusty2": {
            "ID": "rusty2",
            "Service": "rusty",
            "Tags": [],
            "Address": "10.10.10.10",
            "Port": 8002,
            "EnableTagOverride": false,
            "CreateIndex": 19,
            "ModifyIndex": 29
        }
    }
}`

Comment: This is almost correct; you definitely need a unique id for the service, but you should keep the name as "rusty" because you can then query the rusty.service.consul and get detail on both ports back.

Answer (score 1):

As per my comment to @ruslan-sennov, if the `services` section looked like this (the `ID` for each instance of the `rusty` service is made unique by adding the port, but the `name` is kept as `rusty`):

```
"Services": {
  "consul": {
    "ID": "consul",
    "Service": "consul",
    "Tags": [],
    "Address": "",
    "Port": 8300,
    "EnableTagOverride": false,
    "CreateIndex": 5,
    "ModifyIndex": 5
  },
  "rusty": {
    "ID": "rusty:8001",
    "Service": "rusty",
    "Tags": [
      "rusty",
      "rust"
    ],
    "Address": "127.0.0.1",
    "Port": 8001,
    "EnableTagOverride": false,
    "CreateIndex": 247,
    "ModifyIndex": 491
  },
  "rusty": {
    "ID": "rusty:8002",
    "Service": "rusty",
    "Tags": [
      "rusty",
      "rust"
    ],
    "Address": "127.0.0.1",
    "Port": 8002,
    "EnableTagOverride": false,
    "CreateIndex": 247,
    "ModifyIndex": 491
  }
}
```

This then means you can query the `rusty` service with a SRV query and get detail on which ports are available:

```
dig @127.0.0.1 rusty.service.consul SRV

; <<>> DiG 9.11.3 <<>> rusty.service.consul SRV
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 56091
;; flags: qr aa rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 52, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 5

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;rusty.service.consul.                IN      SRV

;; ANSWER SECTION:
rusty.service.consul. 0       IN      SRV     1 1 8001 FB20160707.node.dc1.consul.
rusty.service.consul. 0       IN      SRV     1 1 8002 FB20160707.node.dc1.consul.
```

If you also change the names to be unique (`rusty1` and `rusty2` as suggested by Ruslan) you lose this querying ability.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is late to answer this, but hope this would help someone.

As per [Spring Cloud Consul docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-consul/docs/2.2.4.RELEASE/reference/html/#making-the-consul-instance-id-unique), Add this to `bootstrap.yml`.

```
spring:
  cloud:
    consul:
      discovery:
        instanceId: ${spring.application.name}:${vcap.application.instance_id:${spring.application.instance_id:${random.value}}}
```